# Simple Javascript Calculator, something went wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I tried to make this simple JS calculator following a tutorial I found but it doesn't seem to be working at all. When I press one of the buttons nothing happens. I probably made a really stupid mistake so I'm sorry if I'm wasting your time. I've troubleshooted it but I can't find a solution.

**Correction**: It works now!

```js
var a,b,result;
    function setValues()
    {
     a = Number(document.getElementById("a").value);
     b = Number(document.getElementById("b").value);
    }
    
    function sum()
    {
     setValues();
     result = a+b;
     alert("The sum is equal to"+result);
    }
    
    function rest()
    {
     setValues();
     result = a-b;
     alert("The rest is equal to"+result);
    }
    
    function mult()
    {
     setValues();
     result = a*b;
     alert("The mult is equal to"+result);
    }
    
    function div()
    {
     setValues();
     result = a/b;
     alert("The div is equal to"+result);
    }
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="a" type="text">
  <input id="b" type="text">
  <input type="button" onclick="sum()" value="sum"/>
  <input type="button" onclick="rest()" value="rest"/>
  <input type="button" onclick="mult()" value="multiply"/>
  <input type="button" onclick="div()" value="divide"/>

</div>
```

Comment: what errors are you seeing? anything in your console? is anything being alerted? (n.b use parseInt() rather then Number())

Comment: I've voted to close this as it's a simple typographical error. `getElementByID` should be `getElementById`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that your console (<kbd>F12</kbd>) is throwing error.

Change

```
document.getElementByID("a").value
```

to

```
document.getElementById("a").value
```

JavaScript is Case-Sensitive. So that's why js does not find `getElementByID`

Answer (score 0):

Typo?

```
a = Number(document.getElementByID("a").value);
b = Number(document.getElementByID("b").value);
```

Try:

```
a = Number(document.getElementById("a").value);
b = Number(document.getElementById("b").value);
```

Comment: I create a fiddle for same, http://jsfiddle.net/ucrjp9yn/, made the "ID" to "Id" change, but it's still not working, are you sure the problem is that only?

Comment: @RohitAggarwal yes. The problem in your case is jsfiddle itself. Copy and Paste it into a local file and fire up your favourite browser and it should work.

Comment: Yes, run the snippet above and try for yourself if you want!